# How to load custom .vimrc file, but preserve the rest of the initialization sequence?

Tags: vim

I do `vim -u ~/.my_custom_vimrc some_file`. The first line of .my_custom_vimrc is: `call pathogen#infect()`. I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing .my_custom_vimrc:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
```

The vim manual at `:h -u` says:

> -u {vimrc}      The file {vimrc} is read for initializations.  Most other
>                   initializations are skipped...

I assume, that the plugin that defines pathogen is not loaded. If I rename .my_custom_vimrc to .vimrc the error goes away. And that is what I really want: several .vimrc files so I can decide which one to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the key to this is in the documentation at [`:h -u`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-u), near the end:

> Using the "-u" argument has the side effect that the 'compatible'
>   option will be on by default.

My guess would be that since `pathogen#infect()` makes use of the *autoload* feature, which is definitely not compatible with *vi*, the function call fails. Or perhaps, the `.vim` directory isn't even considered in compatible mode. Whatever the root cause, compatible mode is definitely not what you want when using plugins.

The solution is to force nocompatible mode with the `-N` flag:

```
vim -Nu ~/.myvimrc myfile
```

Comment: Or just adding `set nocompatible` at the top of the alternative vimrc.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve that you can start VIM with an own variable, and then source different files in `.vimrc` depending on that variable.

In your `.vimrc` (showing some different ways of using it):

```
"# this is _not_ an error if env. variable 'what_to_do' isn't used
let WhatToDo = $what_to_do

if WhatToDo == "this"
  "# Use 'source'
  source $HOME/.vim/.vimrc_this
  "# This should not do 'common stuff'
  finish

elseif WhatToDo == "that"
  "# ...or use 'runtime', finds and sources the first file with the given
  "# name looking in folders in 'runtimepath' (default includes e.g. ~/.vim)
  runtime .vimrc_that

else
  runtime .vimrc_default
endif

"# common stuff...
```

Then to use it in Unix command line:

```
$ vim text.txt                  # will use '.vimrc_default'
$ what_to_do=that vim text.txt  # will use '.vimrc_that'
$ # what_to_do is not defined after that line
```

When using an Unix environment variable on the same line as a command, that
variable is only valid for that command. **NB! there can be no space before or
after `=` when setting an Unix variable**.
Or you can set it before:

```
$ what_to_do=that
$ vim text.txt                  # will use '.vimrc_that'
$ # what_to_do has still the value "that" here
```

Or in a script (startvim):

```
what=$1
shift
what_to_do=$what vim "$@"
```

and use it with
`$ startvim that <whatever flags you want> text.txt`

Or the best way perhaps, use one alias for each choice:
`$ alias vim_that='what_to_do=that vim'` then you can use it the same way you use `vim`, with the flags you want. E.g.
`$ vim_that <whatever flags you want> text.txt`

---

There is an alternative to using environment variables, use the flag **--cmd**

> **--cmd** {command}                       *--cmd*         {command} will be executed before processing any vimrc file.        Otherwise it acts like -c {command}.  You
>   can use up to 10 of       these commands, independently from "-c"
>   commands.         {not in Vi}

and start it with
`$ vim --cmd 'let WhatToDo = "that"' text.txt`,
but it's trickier with the alias then
`$ alias vi_that='vi --cmd "let WhatToDo = \"that\""'`
(and you must use
`if ! exists("WhatToDo") | let WhatToDo = "" | endif` in the start of `.vimrc` in that case, to handle when it's not started with that variable, and skip the line with `$what_to_do`).

You can of course use `-c "source the_file_you_want"` and have an empty `.vimrc`, but then the sourcing is maybe not in the same place in the start sequence as having it in the `.vimrc`.

---

Help for this:
[`:h runtime`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#%3aruntime)
[`:h runtimepath`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27runtimepath%27)
[`:h --cmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#--cmd)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-c` to load it:

```
vim -c "so ~/.my_custom_vimrc some_file"
```

Comment: I do not know why, but I the result is different to `vim -u ~/.my_custom_vimrc some_file` — I do not even see the color scheme I am used to.